# I have just started learning about Linked list using C++. I am trying to create a linked list using a vector. Why is the problem with this code?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class node{
public:
    int data;
    node* next;
    
// Constructor
node(int d){
    data = d;
    next = NULL;
}
};

 // Linked List from Vector
void createList(node*& head , vector<int> v){
cout<<v[0];
head->data = v[0];
head->next = NULL;
node* last = head;
for(int i = 1 ; i < v.size() ; i++){
    cout<<"X"<<endl;
    node* temp = new node(v[i]);
    last->next = temp;
    last = temp;
}
cout<<head->data;
  }

// Print Linked list
  void printList(node* head){
  while(head != NULL){
    cout<<head->data;
    head = head->next;
 }
}
int main(){
 vector<int> v = {1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5};
 node* head = NULL;
 createList(head , v);
 cout<<head->data;
 printList(head);
 }
```

This code above is what I used. First I created a vector. Then I created a linked list using tht vector
and then I am trying to print the linked list. But the output is showing nothing.

The output is showing nothing. No error , no output.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). The hint: what is pointed by `head` in the expression `head->data = v[0];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a null pointer (`head`) into `createList`, but you are dereferencing it immediately in the function with this line:

```
head->data = v[0];
```

Before you attempt to use it, `head` must point to something.

Comment: yeah got it i should have allocate the head with memory first...thanx